# Not being able to use margin

Tags: html, css

So I'm not unable to use margin that consists of three texts. I tried adding it both in html and css, none of them worked. Am I supposed to format it in a different way?

```css
.middlelectureread {
  margin-left: 740px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.middlecaptivityread {
  margin-left: 210px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.middleprotestread {
  margin-left: 210px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<span class="middlelectureread">READ MORE</span><span class="middlecaptivityread">READ MORE</span><span 
class="middleprotestread">READ MORE</span>
```

Comment: Try .middlelectureread {display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;}

Answer (score 0):

Like Neffy wrote you shouldn't use `span` here. Span element is inline and shouldn't be a container to postion elements. For such things we have divs or HTML5 semantic elements like `Section`, `Header`, `Footer` etc. `span` can be useful when we want to style for example a part of some text, paragraph.

```
<p>If you do it you will see a <span class="warning">warning</span>sign</p>
```

And if we apply color to this span it will work.

Comment: I fixed it. What about the text and pictures being differently positioned when viewing from different devices? I viewed my site on my computer and on my laptop, on my laptop it displayed the text and pictures more to the left.

Comment: Well it's hart to tell because there is so much ahead of you. But first of all try not to set margins in px. Use for example percentages and see how it behaves.

Comment: It seems to be working fine, I guess. But some of the picture look bigger on the laptop which makes the text look bad

Comment: I don't see your code but it's again probably about pixels. Use percentages as img width as well